# How can I filter search results using Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scraping and I am trying to scrape data from this website https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/uretim/gerceklesen-uretim/gercek-zamanli-uretim.xhtml

When I try to get data without applying filters everything is working. But the data I need should be for a specific power plant and date. I am getting a hard time finding why I cannot apply the filters.

````
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from ..items import EpiasscrapingItem

class EpiasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'epias'
    start_urls =[
        'https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/uretim/gerceklesen-uretim/gercek-zamanli-uretim.xhtml'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
      
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata = {
            'j_idt205':'j_idt205',
            'j_idt205:date1_input' : '20.03.2021',
            'j_idt205:date2_input' : '20.03.2021',
            'j_idt205:powerPlant_input' : '2614',
 
        }, callback=self.start_scraping)

    def start_scraping(self,response):
        items = EpiasscrapingItem()

        table_epias = response.css('.ui-datatable-odd')

        for epias in table_epias:
            date = epias.css('.ui-widget-content .TexAlCenter:nth-child(1)').css('::text').extract()
            time = epias.css('.ui-widget-content .TexAlCenter:nth-child(2)').css('::text').extract()
            biogas = epias.css('.ui-widget-content .TexAlCenter:nth-child(15)').css('::text').extract()

            items['date'] = date 
            items['time'] = time 
            items['biogas'] = biogas 

            yield items```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include `javax.faces.ViewState` and few other fields within parameters supposed to be sent with post requests. You can now change the value of `date1_input`, `date2_input` and `powerPlant_input` to fetch the relevant content. The following script should work:

```
class EpiasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'epias'
    
    start_urls = [
        'https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/uretim/gerceklesen-uretim/gercek-zamanli-uretim.xhtml'
    ]

    post_url = 'https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/uretim/gerceklesen-uretim/gercek-zamanli-uretim.xhtml'

    def parse(self, response):
        payload = {
            'j_idt205': 'j_idt205',
            'j_idt205:date1_input': '11.02.2021',
            'j_idt205:date2_input': '20.03.2021',
            'j_idt205:powerPlant_focus': '',
            'j_idt205:powerPlant_input': '2336',
            'j_idt205:goster': '',
            'j_idt205:dt_rppDD': '24',
            'javax.faces.ViewState': response.css(".ContainerIndent input[name='javax.faces.ViewState']::attr(value)").get()
        }

        yield scrapy.FormRequest(self.post_url,formdata=payload,callback=self.parse_content)

    def parse_content(self,response):
        for epias in response.css('.ui-datatable-odd'):
            items = {}
            date = epias.css('tr.ui-widget-content > .TexAlCenter:nth-child(1)::text').get()
            time = epias.css('tr.ui-widget-content > .TexAlCenter:nth-child(2)::text').get()
            total = epias.css('tr.ui-widget-content > .TexAlCenter:nth-child(3)::text').get()

            items['date'] = date 
            items['time'] = time 
            items['total'] = total 
            yield items
```